# Show that the conditional variance $\{h_t\}$ of a GARCH process is an ARMA($m,p-1$) process

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, garch

This is question 10.6(c) from Time Series and Forecasting (2nd Edition) by Brockwell and Davis. The parts (a) and (b) of this question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724055/expectation-and-variance-of-garchp-q) in another SE question.

**Question**: Suppose that $\{Z_t\}$ is a causal stationary GARCH($p, q$) process with $Z_t = \sqrt{h_t}e_t$,
where $\{e_t\} \sim$ IID($0,1)$, $\sum_{i=1}^p a_i +\sum_{j=1}^q \beta_q < 1$ and $$ h_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p a_i Z^2_{t-i} + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j h_{t-j}.$$

Define  $m = \max(p,q)$, $a_i = 0$ for $i > p$ and $\beta_j = 0$ for $j > q$, $U_t = Z^2_t - h_t$ and $V_t = a_1^{-1}U_{t-1}$, and $a^*_j = \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_1}$ for $j=1,\ldots,p-1$.

For $p\geq1$,show that the conditional variance $\{h_t\}$ is an ARMA($m,p-1$) process, where $$h_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i + \beta_i) h_{t-i} + V_t + a^*_1 V_{t-1} + \ldots + a^*_p V_{t-p-1}.$$

[I think there may be a typo in the book, and the AR part should either be of order $p+1$ or $p-1$, depending on whether the text or displayed maths is correct.]

**My attempt:** We write $U_t$ in terms of $Z_t$ and $h_t$: $$Z_t^2 = h_t + U_t.$$

Now, we use the defining equation for $h_t$, and then replace in the above expression:

$$ h_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p a_i (h_{t-i} + U_{t-i}) + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j h_{t-j}.$$

We can identify $a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p a_i h_{t-i} + \sum_{j=1}^q \beta_j h_{t-j}$ as the sum $a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i + \beta_j) h_{t-i}$.

For the term $\sum_{i=1}^p a_i U_{t-i} = \sum_{i=1}^p \frac{a_i}{a_1} a_1 U_{t-i}$, I cannot see how to get it into the correct form. By replacing $a^*_{i-1} = a_{i}/a_1$ and $a_1 V_t = U_{t-1}$, I obtain the expression $$\sum_{i=1}^p a^*_{i-1} a_1^2 V_{t-i+1}.$$

This work leads me to believe that the displayed maths in the book had a typo, and the AR part should be of order $p-1$. I also think that the definition of either $a^*_j$ or $V_t$ may have a typo? If I instead use $V_t = a_1 U_{t-1}$, I get the answer $$h_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i + \beta_i) h_{t-i} + V_t + a^*_1 V_{t-1} + \ldots + a^*_{p-1} V_{t-p+1}. $$   Could someone please let me know if I have made a mistake? Thank you for your help!